# Concurrent Downloads with win_get_url

Tags: windows, ansible

I have a challenge I'm trying to figure out.
We are building AMI's with AWS Codebuild. At one point in our playbook we are reaching out and downloading patches from artifcatory and it takes forever since it's downloading them one at a time. I'm hoping to find a way to have concurrent downloads, perhaps 3 at a time, to speed up this process. The code for the download is listed below. Nothing super secret about it.

Appreciate any help!

```
- name: download service patches
  win_get_url:
    url: "{{ service_patches_url.json.uri | regex_replace('/api/storage') }}{{ item.uri }}"
    dest: "{{ service_patches_folder }}\\{{ item.uri | regex_replace('^/(.*)$', '\\1') }}"
    proxy_url: "{{ proxy_url }}"
    use_proxy: "{{ use_proxy }}"
    force: no
  until: service_patches_download is not failed
  retries: 3
  register: service_patches_download
  with_items: "{{ service_patches_url.json.children }}"
  when: service_patches_url.status_code == 200
```